# How to Identify records containing similar texts from a mssql table

Tags: java, sql-server

I am having a table containing multiple records with different or similar or partially similar texts.

For example:

record 1 : Stack overflow forum is very useful. This helps developers and researchers a most.
record 2 : There are several very useful forums available that helps developers and researchers.

record 3 : This stack overflow forum is very useful. This helps developers and researchers a most.
record 4: This text should not be considered.

consider record 1 and record 3, both are same and it is marked as duplicate as i am generating hash code for the records.

record 4 contains totally different text.

Take a look at record 1 and record 2, both resembles mostly similar meaning and contains nearly similar words.

When comparing both records Percentage of similar words is greater in these two records.

So i need to extract these types of records based on the percentage.

Is there any algorithm related to java to perform this?

It will be useful for me if i get some guidance.

Comment: Your actual question is: I need a Java algorithm to calculate string similarity. The other 90% of the question text is irrelevant. And I suggest you google for that first, because asking for resources is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fuzzy string search for your requirement.
May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327513/fuzzy-string-search-in-java) post help you out.
Or for search in DB you can also use Hibernate search. See [Hibernate Querying](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html)