# How to compare two strings in Java with error margin

Tags: java, string, compare

I am working on a game where the user has to fill in a name of a celebrity. If the name is not 100% correct but nearly correct, the compare should succeed. Is there a ready to use function in java or something someone ever has written so I can use it ?

Comment: "Fuzzy" is the word you are looking for.

Comment: You could compare it letter by letter and check how many a user got right compared to what it actually is.

Comment: This might be a too broad question, Please define your threshold for `If the name is not 100% correct but nearly correct`.

Comment: Maybe you find something in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/327513/982149

Comment: You may be looking for something like the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to define similarity of the strings.

Comment: @Fildor You are right, that is what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Levenshtein algortithm

You'll find here some Java implementations : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java

Or, if you don't want/need to understand how it works, you can get the score directly from Apache StringUtils : [getLevenshteinDistance](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

And if you want to get the percentage of similarities, you can do :

```
int lev = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(s1, s2);
double ratio = ((double) lev) / (Math.max(s1.length, s2.length));
```