# Efficient String Search Using Dictionary Java

Tags: java, dictionary, string-matching, aho-corasick

I want to implement Dictionary Based approach for String Matching in Java which should be time efficient. To explain further Implementation should be based on the Fuzzy Match score. I have tried several implementations like Aho coresick but not getting desired result. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: [Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327513/fuzzy-string-search-library-in-java). It will perhaps point you in the right direction,

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project for Fuzzy Matching strings. See if this helps
https://github.com/intuit/fuzzy-matcher